# Neo4j delete, update multiple nodes and connections

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have the following schema in Neo4J:

[image]

Short description:

- Nodes 1, 2, 3 (black) from "Helmut" are feed posts.
- Nodes 1,2,3,4,5,6 (red) from "Doe" are feed posts. But nodes 1,2 from "Doe" are shares of 2 and then 1 from "Helmut". So Node 1 from Doe is a share of node 2 from "Helmut" and node 2 from "Doe" is a share of node 1 from "Helmut". The shared nodes are connected with an "ORIGIN" connection so I can get the privacy property of the original node.

I want to delete node "Helmut" and with him do the following steps:

1. break (delete) the connections "livesInCity", "livesInCountry", "isFriendsWith" of user "Helmut"
2. Other users, such as "Doe", have nodes that are connected with other nodes via an "ORIGIN" connection. This means that this nodes are shares from another node. In my example user "Doe" nodes 1 and 2 are shares of "Helmut"s nodes. All the nodes that have an "ORIGIN" connection with green nodes from user "Helmut" (connected with FEED_ITEMS or NEXT) needs to have status "deleted" - this is just a string saying "deleted".
3. delete all feed_items and next nodes that are coming from user "Helmut"
4. delete user "Helmut" node.

I am pretty new on neo4j so I wonder if this can be achieved in a single query or it needs to be processed separately.

I would expect that at some point there will be a lot of nodes with an "ORIGIN" connection. The origin connection means that this is a feed share. I wonder what does this mean in terms of speed to set a lot of nodes with status "deleted". I will need to do this in a separate call (for example in as a MQ process) or it will be fine to do it on form/url server request?

Also if I delete the node "Helmut" and not the connections, between countries and cities let's say, will those connection remain there as ghost connections or they will be deleted once the node is gone?

Comment: Can you rephrase step #2? I find it very unclear. For example, what does 'the first and second node of "Doe"' mean? And exactly which nodes need to have the "delete" status, and is that a boolean "delete" property or a string "status" property, or ...?

Comment: @cybersam hey, please check my updated question. I hope i made it clear enough this time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know how many shares exist from a deleted user's posts, it's probably best to do a batch modification of these, followed by batch deletes. We can use apoc.periodic.iterate() from APOC Procedures for this.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate("
MATCH (d:Doctor {name:${nameToDelete})-[:FEED_ITEM]->()-[:NEXT*0..]->(feedItem)
OPTIONAL MATCH (feedItem)<-[:ORIGIN]-(share)
RETURN feedItem, share",
"SET share.status = 'deleted'
 WITH DISTINCT feedItem
 DETACH DELETE feedItem", {}) YIELD batches, total, errorMessages
 RETURN batches, total, errorMessages
```

This uses a default batchSize of 10k entries at a time (streamed from the outer query, then the inner query is applied to the batch)

Either in the same query (after the procedure call) or a separate one, you can do a MATCH and DETACH DELETE of the doctor to delete.

Neo4j doesn't allow dangling relationships, all of a node's relationships must be deleted before the node can be deleted, and DETACH DELETE is used to delete both the relationships of the node as well as the node itself at the same time.